# Rationale find command display . directory

Tags: find

I am wondering what the reason or rationale is for the find command to list the current directory ( . ) at some times but not others.

When I use ".", I see the current directory in the outer directory but not the inner directory.

```
$ pwd
/home/me/a

$ find . -exec echo  {} \;
.
./abc.txt
./a.txt
./d
./d/da.txt
```

When I give the specific directory, I do not see the current directory.

```
$ find /home/me/a  -exec echo  {} \;
/home/me/a
/home/me/a/abc.txt
/home/me/a/a.txt
/home/me/a/d
/home/me/a/d/da.txt
```

Here is how ls sees the situation.

```
$ ls -lR
.:
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r--. 1 me    0 Oct 20 19:03 abc.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 me    0 Oct 21 14:56 a.txt
drwxr-xr-x. 2 me 4.0K Oct 21 14:57 d/

./d:
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 me 0 Oct 21 14:57 da.txt
```

Comment: I was confused by the appearance of the ".".  For the inner directories, it is giving the . followed by the directory name.

It seems find is using the syntax of the inputted directory reference.

Robert

Answer (score 5):

The dot being displayed in the output of `find` is just the current location as you specified it with the `find .` command. Same too when you say `find /home/me/a`. In both cases find is showing you the directory you're searching in (as specified) and any corresponding files and directories that `find` finds in that location.

#### Examples

*directory we're looking inside of is `.`*

```
$ find . ....
.
./abc.txt
./a.txt
```

Find shows the results in terms of the argument you specified, i.e. `.`.

*directory we're looking inside of is `/home/me/a`*

```
$ find /home/me/a ....
/home/me/a
/home/me/a/abc.txt
/home/me/a/a.txt
```

Again `find` shows the results in terms of the argument you specified, `/home/me/a`.

#### Terminology

Try not to think of them in terms of inner or outer, think of the specification as relative or absolute. Relative is `.` and absolute is `/home/me/a`. In either case `find` doesn't care, it just shows the directories and files it finds from that location down.

Answer (score 1):

Using the relative directory (the `find .`) produces expected results of `./abc.txt` while `find /home/ma/a/abc.txt` is identical but absolute.  You would not expect to see `.` when using absolute paths.

The results are identical in that you could technically "find and replace" the `.` with `/home/me/a` and vice-versa.